# download file from server with the jQuery fileDownload plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, download

I am using the `$.fileDownload` Plugin from John Culviner, my goal is to download a file which is located on a server. I am using **ASP.NET** Web Forms. Here is my code which I use.

## My JavaScript code is this

```
$("#btnDownload").click(function () {
                     $.support.cors = true;
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "GET",
                         url: "http://localhost/GetData/9", 
                         processdata: false, 
                         success: function (msg) {  
                                    $.fileDownload("http://localhost/fileDownload.txt", {  
                                       successCallback: function (url) {  
                                         alert('You just got a file download dialog or ribbon for this URL :' + url); 
                                    },  
                                       failCallback: function (html, url) {    
                                         alert('Your file download just failed for this URL:' + url + '\r\n' +     
                                              'Here was the resulting error HTML: \r\n' + html);    
                                    }
                         }                       
                    }); 
});
```

## My "ServerCode" a WCF Webservice

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetDaten/{value}", Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void GetData(string value)
{
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fileDownload.txt");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/fileDownload.txt"));
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

}
```

Can someone say me what I have configure wrong, the $.fileDownload method jump always in the failCallback method.

Comment: Can you provide the message from failCallback method? In Html Url paramters is there any error message?

Comment: no, there comes no information

Comment: It's intresting, that you make an ajax request manually, and then you don't do anything with response, and then you make call in the success callback the $.fileDownload which probably makes another ajax request to the same url. Does the first manual request necessary?

Comment: in the url stands the url http://localhost/fileDownload.txt

Comment: speti43, do you know the fileDownload plugin?

Comment: I'm examining now, couple of minutes

Comment: I haven't seen this type of usage in the demo page.

Comment: do you mean the ajax-method is not important? But I need it, because I want to give the user a dynamic generated file, which is based on a webservice call

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btnDownload").click(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;                    
        $.fileDownload("http://localhost/fileDownload.txt", {  
               successCallback: function (url) {  
                   alert('You just got a file download dialog or ribbon for this URL :' + url); 
                   },  
                   failCallback: function (html, url) {    
                   alert('Your file download just failed for this URL:' + url + '\r\n' +     
                                          'Here was the resulting error HTML: \r\n' + html);    
                   }
        }                      

});
```

I think the first ajax request is unecessary.

Because this makes the request also:
$.fileDownload

Server code:
In the demo (MVC3 app) he uses the controller to send the file from the server to the client.
Inside the controller there is a FilePathResult type function. 
Try this way, maybe it works, but I can't try it now.

```
public FilePathResult GetData(string value)
{  
    return File("~/fileDownload.txt", "text/plain", "fileDownload.txt");
}
```

Comment: try to modify the signature:
public void GetData(object value)

Comment: no this is not possible, because the parameters must be string value

Comment: I think it's correct, I'had similar issue with soap webservice, and if you dont pass the correct type of object from javascript to the service, it will fails, and do not hit the server code. with object you can receive any type of parameter. Just modify it and try, and if it's good, we can find out what to do.

Comment: it is not possible I have test it, the server code is activated, but I can't download the file

Comment: the FilePathResult class is not accessable through Web Forms, the classes are defined in the System.Web.Mvc namespace: Thank you that you still invest time for me

Comment: I think you can start to search for a better more supported and documented solution for this porpuse.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution here: [WCF Streaming: Upload/Download Files Over HTTP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP)
Maybe you can integrate with your jquery plugin.